# Able to access Documentation Beta in Stack Exchange App

Tags: bug, status-declined, android-app, ios-app, documentation

Currently, the Documentation Beta is in private beta. Thus, users who do not have an invite will not be able to view contents in Documentation, including the Users list and Questions at http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com.

However in the Stack Exchange App, under 'All Sites' in the menu bar, if a user without an invite searches for 'Documentation' and enters Documentation Beta site, he will be able to access all the questions and view all users currently in Documentation Beta even though he is not invited.

This works in the iOS App, not sure if it works in the Android App.

Is this a flaw or is it designed to be work this way?

Comment: AFAIK it is always possible to access a private beta, one known route is to subscribe via Area51. In that sense it isn't so private that its content should be hidden from the world by all possible means. It just a barrier to keep random visitors, search engines and those that don't dare to experiment  away from the site. So expect this to be status-bydesign

Comment: @rene Thanks, but Documentation isn't a Area 51 beta, usually for Area 51 private betas, they are both accessible online at their websites and in App. One such example is the Latin Language which is currently in Private Beta - https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions.

Comment: [Status-bydesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200064/committed-but-non-invited-area-51-private-beta-is-accessible-via-android-app)

Comment: @rene: I marked it [status-declined] because it's not exactly part of the design, but we aren't going to change the behavior either.

Comment: Can confirm access via Android App (found this thread when found it there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Q&A site you can see via the app (or if you had access to Documentation, via the site itself) is a sort of meta for the private beta. Once the feature goes live on Stack Overflow, this meta will be the canonical place to ask questions about the new content type. At that point, any questions still relevant will be migrated here, but most of the Q&A will be archived offline.

I don't think anyone *planned* on having the Documentation pseudo-meta made available on the mobile app. So it's probably technically a bug. But on the other hand, it's not really worth fixing either.

Comment: @JonClements: I declined it. Six of one. . .

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation :)